# Block wise author and affiliation

Tags: line-breaking, titles, ieeetran

I am using `IEEEtran` class and I am quite new to LaTeX how can I achieve this output in proper format using `IEEEtran` class.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The total width of the author blocks is too wide to fit within the text block margins, so it rolls over to the next line. If you wish to keep this format, you need to reduce the size of some of some of the content, abbreviate them, or combine them. For example, I tried with `\small Vellore Institute of Technology` which seems to work:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\title{Sample paper}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Taher Ali Rangwala}%
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\small Vellore Institute of Technology \\
    taheralirangwala@gmail.com} \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Manish Dipankar}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\small Vellore Institute of Technology \\
    manishdipankar@gmail.com} \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Saikiran Chanda}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\small Vellore Institute of Technology \\
    saikiran@gmail.com} \and
  \IEEEauthorblockN{Shanu Kumar}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{\small Vellore Institute of Technology \\
    shanukumar@gmail.com}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

However, the [`IEEEtran` class](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) mentions something in this regard:

> If there are more than three authors and/or the text is too
>   wide to fit across the page, use an alternate long format [...]
>   The `\IEEEauthorrefmark{}` command will generate a footnote
>   symbol corresponding to the number in its argument. Use
>   this to link the author names to their respective affiliations. It is
>   not necessary prevent spaces from being between the `\IEEEauthorblock`'s because each block starts a new group of lines
>   and LaTeX will ignore spaces at the very end and beginning of
>   lines.

Here is an example of this, directly from the documentation:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\title{Sample paper}

\author{
  \IEEEauthorblockN{
    Michael Shell\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, 
    Homer Simpson\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, 
    James Kirk\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}, 
    Montgomery Scott\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and 
    Eldon Tyrell\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{
    \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Electrical and Computer Engineering \\
      Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta, Georgia 30 332--0250 \\
      Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Twentieth Century Fox, Springfield, USA \\
      Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Starfleet Academy, San Francisco, California 96678-2391 \\
      Telephone: (800) 555--1212, Fax: (888) 555--1212}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}Tyrell Inc., 123 Replicant Street, Los Angeles, California 90210--4321}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```